# Orbeon Tree View

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm trying to mimic a desktop program in .NET [image: desktop program to mimic] (which generates XML file) by using Orbeon XForms Engine 3.9

How do I create the sidebar with the tree view using Orbeon ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `appearance="xxforms:tree"` for `<xforms:select>` and `<xforms:select1>` tags which will show you the options in Tree view. See:

- [The documentation for the tree appearance](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-controls/selection-controls#TOC-Tree-appearance)
- [A full example with different selects using the tree appearance](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/apps/xforms-sandbox/samples/tree.xhtml)